# json parse using javascript

Tags: javascript

hi guy i try to show an alert using this

[example code](http://jsfiddle.net/Leg3g4jc/1/)

```
var resultado = [{
    "act_dedicarte": "Estudios complementarios (ingl",
    "total": "3"
}, {
    "act_dedicarte": "Estudios universitarios o supe",
    "total": "280"
}, {
    "act_dedicarte": "Ninguna de las anteriores",
    "total": "1"
}, {
    "act_dedicarte": "Trabajar",
    "total": "5"
}, {
    "act_dedicarte": "Trabajar y estudiar",
    "total": "50"
}]


resultado.rows.forEach(function(esteElemento) {
    alert(esteElemento.total);
});
```

i try to alert the total but is not work. can you help me?

Comment: get rid of `.rows`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `resultado.rows` to

```
resultado.forEach(function(esteElemento) {
    alert(esteElemento.total);
});
```